# Possible to keeping file suffix on Google Cloud Storage for Twilio API?

Tags: amazon-s3, twilio, google-cloud-storage

I am building a Twilio app on Google Cloud to play an mp3 file.

```
# Play an MP3 file
resp = VoiceResponse()
resp.play("http://demo.twilio.com/hellomonkey/monkey.mp3")
```

This works if the audio link is the Twilio link above or a link to Amazon S3 (https://s3.amazonaws.com/ivr-test-for-twilio/monkey.mp3)

However, when I try to use a Google Cloud Storage link:
  https://storage.cloud.google.com/ivr-test/266696687/monkey.mp3 
, the app fails. (The file is correctly labelled in Google Cloud with Type "audio/mpeg".)

If you click on the Google Cloud Storage link above, you see it redirects to a longer link that no longer has the ".mp3" in its name, but plays a monkey call correctly.

However, Twilio's API doesn't work with this link. I'm guessing because this function accepts multiple audio types. it's looking for the suffix ".mp3" to know to treat the file as an mp3

**Is there a way to force Google Cloud Storage files to have a certain suffix?** I think this file would play if it had the proper suffix and ended in .mp3.  I can imagine lots of programs looking at the suffix of a file and acting accordingly.

I can use Amazon S3 as a workaround, but since the app is build on Google Cloud, I'd like to put it all in one place.

Comment: I think the problem is that your mp3 link is protected by Google (you need to log in to your account) and obviously Twilio's servers can't do that. It just needs to be a straight forward link to a mp3 file (no login needed). I'm also not sure if Twilio will follow redirects or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use  https://storage.cloud.google.com. Use https://storage.googleapis.com

That first domain can be used for viewing a GCS resource on the web as a human in a web browser with a Google account. It may do various redirects, such as prompting you to sign in. For any other purpose, you want the other domain, storage.googleapis.com.

Your other problem is that you need to mark the file as publicly readable so that Twilio can read the object.  You can do this in the Cloud Console by selecting the checkbox in the SHARED PUBLICLY column for the object. For more, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_sharingdata

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. I checked the "Share publicly" box on the right side, and right-clicked on "Public Link" to get a storage.google.apis.com  link.